# Codeigniter Database connection error on Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cpanel

This is my current scenerio
1. I am on Live Shared Hosting using Cpanel. 
2. when i tried to connect to database using following configuration

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user_dbuser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'user_dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['port'] = '3306';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

it gave error message like :

```
An Error Was Encountered
Your application/config/database.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.
```

So in order to find the error, i placed the following code near the end of config/database.php.

```
$OK = mysql_select_db ($db['default']['database']);
if ($OK) // 
{
// Nothing required, everything OK
// fred($db['default'], 'Database setting -->  $db["default"]');
}else{
echo '<h1>Something terrible has happened</h1>';
echo '<pre>';
    echo $db['default'];
echo '</pre>';
die;
}
```

This gives the following output.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user 'taxac'@'localhost' (using  password: NO)

Filename: config/database.php

Line Number: 69

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established

Filename: config/database.php

Line Number: 69

Something terrible has happened


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message:  Array to string conversion
Filename: config/database.php
Line Number: 77

Array
```

**I request you to please notice the lines in the above error**

> "Access denied for user 'taxac'@'localhost' (using  password: NO)"

**why it is not Using Password and how to make it use "Password"**.

in order to verify the credentials, i tried to connect to mysql with following script

```
// TRY TO LOGIN WITH SIMPLE PHP NATIVE SCRIPT
$link = mysql_connect
(
$db['default']['hostname'], 
$db['default']['username'], 
$db['default']['password']
);

if (!$link) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
else echo "MySQL connected";


// check the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db['default']['database'], $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use <b>' .$db['default']['database'] .'</b> : ' . mysql_error());
}  
else die('database is selected');
```

and succeeded with following output

```
MySQL Connected.
database is selected
```

So I am sure that

**1. The DB Credentials i provided are correct **

**2. I have selected proper sql extension**
**3. Error is somehow related to following error line in the fourth output above **

> "Access denied for user 'taxac'@'localhost' (using  password: NO)"

So please help how to make it to use Password to connect to DB.

Comment: this output from localhost or from live ?

Comment: if you are connecting in live server then you will see that for database name, database user some prefix has already been generated before you input for your database name, database user name. So use the database name, database user name with full prefix. You don't need to comment out the port. It will work. If it does not work then let me know.

Comment: The above output is from a live host and i am using Database name and DB user name with correct and full prefixes as you can see i am able to connect through simple php script.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out

```
$db['default']['port'] = '3306';
```

and if that doesn't work check the collation and character settings.

Comment: need not to comment out the port number rather need to use the database name , database username whatever with full prefix.